# Troubleshooting in Docker container by their own developer

Tags: docker, orchestration

We have multiple services which are written in Laravel and Lumen frameworks.

We containerize them with Docker and each source has its own Dockerfile. Is there any solutions to let developers work on these container on live server?

I mean, how can we give them an access just for working and troubleshooting in the containers and if some mistake happened, then just recreate a new container from that image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was my headache too!

Did you work with [docker UCP](https://docs.docker.com/datacenter/ucp/2.1/guides/)!?

It's the best platform for managing docker images container and services!

In there you can define some users and roles for your developers to work on all containers and as you know if something happend on that container or a sys file remove by a mistake you just need to create a new container form your images!

Comment: Thank you for your response.i did not know that in docker.i read the document and it is exactly what i want for our developers